# Select customer attributes that are true and give back in specific order

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am using excel 2010 and I am having for each `customer id` certain events that can be `true` or `false`.

Furthermore a user can configure the order in which the true events for a customer ID should be given back.

So for example I have the following customers with the following events:

```
| Customer ID   | Event 1   | Event 2   | Event 3   | Event 4   |
|-------------  |---------  |---------  |---------  |---------  |
| 1             | TRUE      | FALSE     | TRUE      | FALSE     |
| 2             | FALSE     | TRUE      | FALSE     | FALSE     |
| 3             | TRUE      | TRUE      | TRUE      | TRUE      |
| 4             | FALSE     | TRUE      | FALSE     | FALSE     |
| 5             | TRUE      | FALSE     | TRUE      | TRUE      |
| 6             | TRUE      | TRUE      | FALSE     | FALSE     |
| 8             | FALSE     | FALSE     | TRUE      | TRUE      |
| 9             | TRUE      | TRUE      | FALSE     | TRUE      |
```

Secondly, the order all true events should be given back can be prioritized:

```
| Events    | Prioritized (1...most important - 4... least important)   |
|---------  |---------------------------------------------------------  |
| Event 3   | 1                                                         |
| Event 1   | 2                                                         |
| Event 2   | 3                                                         |
| Event 4   | 4                                                         |
```

So for example, for customer with ID `3` the following output and order of events should be given:

[image]

For a customer with ID `8` the following output and order of events should be given:

[image]

My example excel looks like the following:

[image]

I was thinking of using several `IFs`, however in reality I have around `100 events` and `10.000 customers`.

Any suggestions how to implement this in excel?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: With that many inputs and outputs a formula is not what one should use.  A formula would be array type and that many (1,000,000) would bog down the calc times.  As to vba, what have you tried?  Where does it fail?

Comment: @ScottCraner Thx for your hints! This is not intended to be used in production, so I was looking for a simple formula as I am trying to create a first prototype. Havent`t tried using vba with this app yet. If you have an idea for a formula I would highly appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($H$3:$H$6,AGGREGATE(15,7,(ROW($H$3:$H$6)-MIN(ROW($H$3:$H$6))+1)/(INDEX(INDEX(B:E,MATCH($A$19,A:A,0),0),N(IF({1},MODE.MULT(IF({1},MATCH($H$3:$H$6,$B$2:$E$2,0)*{1,1})))))=TRUE),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

Being an array formula you need to put this in B19 hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter and then copy down.

The one caveat is the list of order be sorted in order.  This does not look at the number in column I but the order in Column H that the events are listed.

`N(IF({1},MODE.MULT(IF({1},MATCH($H$3:$H$6,$B$2:$E$2,0)*{1,1})))))` creates an array of the relative column numbers(B:E) in order they are listed in Column H.

`INDEX(B:E,MATCH($A$19,A:A,0),0)` returns the the row where the customer id is found.

`INDEX(INDEX(B:E,MATCH($A$19,A:A,0),0),N(IF({1},MODE.MULT(IF({1},MATCH($H$3:$H$6,$B$2:$E$2,0)*{1,1})))))` returns the full array of TRUE/FALSE from the correct row in the correct order.

The aggregate then returns the first relative column number that is true and then the second and the third... as it is dragged down to the outer index.  Which then returns the correct value from column H.

If no True is found at the correct `k` then it returns an error and the IFERROR returns a null string.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I've tried your example and I can't make it work. The formula doesn't return any result

Comment: @Kaiser see edit for explanation, and are you entering it with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  This is an array formula.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!! I definitely use ctrl-Shift-enter so i get the brackets. I found the mistake, i had the columns H and I on the wrong row.

Comment: Remove the IFERROR part of the formula see what error you are getting.

Comment: One question, what does `{1,1}` in your formula stand for?

Comment: @Anna.Klee we are doing an array multiplication which allows the number being multiplied to be doubled in the array to make sure that `MODE.MULT` picks it up.

Comment: Hello Scott, I am facing issues in implementing the formula within my excel sheet. I executed it as array-formula, however, I still get for this part `N(IF({1},MODE.MULT(IF({1},MATCH($H$3:$H$6,$B$2:$E$2,0)*{1,1})))))` a `#NV`error, even when the formula is executed as array-formula. Would you be so kind to provide your excel sheet with the solution via file share(google drive, dropbox etc.)? I would highly appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

I came up with an option that's not perfect but should work.

First of all I'd convert your table to a list so it would look like that:

[image]

Right, after I'd create a Helper Column that would act as unique_Reference id for each true column showing the id and the priority:

[image]

The value would be "id"_"priority" using the formula (for Cell B3):

```
 =IF(E3=TRUE,C3&"_"&VLOOKUP(D3,$G$3:$H$7,2,FALSE),"")
```

And then, I'd create the result list which have the issue of getting blanks due to not using array formulas for saving calc time:

[image]

Where formula for cell L3 (event with max priority) would be:

```
=+IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP($L$2&"_"&K3,$B$3:$D$8,3,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP($L$2&"_"&K3,$B$3:$D$8,3,FALSE))
```